# Error in build.gradle file in the terminal

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, build.gradle

For some reason, I am getting an error under my build.gradle file in the side bar. there is no error in the actual code however. what could be causing this and will it affect my app if I want to pull from firestore?

I am using android studio 3.5[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj3Lf.png) on Mac.

Comment: You are not sharing the "error" itself. You just share your build.gradle file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal for that error to be there. Since you're not opening the project as an Android project, but rather as a Flutter project, the IDE tries to identify the build.gradle file on the android folder, even though it doesn't have to do so. You can see that this happens even with a new project if you open that file.

You can just ignore that.

The real errors, if present, will appear when you try to run or build your flutter application.